# Trouble with manual installation of Ubuntu Studio 20.10

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ubuntu-studio

I like to set up my PCs with such that my root directory and home directory are on different partitions.  I have a Dell Latitude E6440 laptop where I attempted this.  The laptop has a 500Gb SDD and 16Gb RAM.  I first tried the install with GPT in UEFI mode (secure boot off, fast boot set to "fast", with choices "minimal", "fast", and "auto").  I partitioned the SDD with 512Mb boot-efi (boot flag), 100Gb root, 8Mb unformatted (boot_grub flag), and the remainder of the disk as my home directory.  This did not work, and threw an error message that (I think) read "unable to copy iniitramfs".  So, I turned UEFI off, and tried the install with MBR, partitioning the SDD with 1 Gb /boot (boot flag), 4 Gb swap (linuxswap), 95 Gb root directory and the remainder as my home directory.  Again, it did not work, with the error message "invalid partition table!".  I finally managed to install Ubuntu Studio by choosing "Erase" and letting the installer to the work.  What am I doing wrong?  If possible, I would like to install Ubuntu Studio with GPT and a separate root and home directory.

Comment: I think the first option you tried should be fine, I'm just not sure about the order. Perhaps the 8MB boot_grub partition needs to be the first. Also, you should not forget to install the bootloader into the device, i.e. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1 or something.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.  I'll check where the bootloader was installed; I did not look at that.  I'll try moving the boot_grub partition.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the BIOS setup on the laptop, and compared it to the settings on my desktop (which does have Ubuntu Studio 20.10 installed with GPT). I ended up setting the Boot List option to UEFI, disabled Legacy ROMs, set the SATA operation to AHCI, and made sure secure boot was not enabled. I then set up three partitions (GPT):

- 512 Mb `fat32` mounted on `boot-efi` with the **boot** flag
- 95 Gb `ext4` mounted as root (`/`)
- 385 Gb (or so) `ext4` mounted as `/home`.

I then installed Ubuntu Studio, and it installed with no errors. Thanks again for everyone's suggestions.